# Running an example class

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and I'm having trouble viewing this class that someone has made.

The link to the class is:
http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=86867&d=1323127879

I did the following steps:
1. Create a new project with a form
2. Add the above class
3. Create an object of the class in my form load sub as:

```
Dim newClass As VisualStudiosTabControl = New VisualStudiosTabControl
```

But when i try to run it I get a whole bunch of build errors like:

Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.ScrollableControlDesigner' is not defined.

and

'Control' is not a member of 'Tab_Control_Example.VisualStudiosTabControl.VisualStudiosTabPage.VisualStudiosTabDesigner'.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: the relevant code here ought to be here not in another castle

Comment: You probably need a reference to System.Windows.Forms.Design.

Comment: This is what happens when you copy/paste code from the internet before learning the fundamentals of the language and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many of the parent files and this looks to be designed to be added onto a project. Try to load whiten your solution of your project.